# Convert comments (which the OP thinks are great) to an answer on a low-quality question, or let it die?

Tags: discussion, answers, question-quality

(update, the OP deleted his own question after it got another downvote.  This is probably the best outcome.)

On https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44857855/how-to-improve-data-heavy-calculation-performance, I made a couple suggestions in comments about caching results.

The OP apparently thought my comments were very interesting/helpful, so I considered just copying them into an answer.  But question is too vague to be able to add any more detail and write a high-quality answer.  (It was already downvoted once with no upvotes when I first saw it.  With 3 close votes for too-broad and unclear.  One of those close-votes is mine.)

I'm not confident that anyone in the future would search and find that question.  Someone searching would probably learn about caching from another search hit, too, so answering this question would probably not be helpful.

Was I correct to restrain myself from answering, or do people think my comments posted as an answer would be a good thing?

Part of my reason for wondering is that I'm not sure whether ideas like caching query results are considered common knowledge, or whether it just seems that way to me because I'm a performance / micro-optimization geek.

Answer (score 1):

Scattering useful information all over the place in hard-to-find posts is probably not useful compared to posting an answer on an existing good question on the topic.  Or even writing up a self-answered Q&A.  Or just leaving a comment or edit on an existing good answer on the same topic.

Even if I did have some gem of wisdom share with the world (which this wasn't), that question would have been the wrong place to do it.

Comment: Yes, basically this. You already know that you shouldn't answer questions you've voted to close, because closure is often the first step to deletion. That makes it a wasted effort. Furthermore, many members of the community believe you shouldn't reward low-quality questions with good answers, since that encourages people to keep asking them. It's naturally up to you if you want to give someone a hint in the form of a comment, pushing them in the right direction (but there are those who would discourage you from that, too).

Comment: Finding an existing question that you could answer, or creating a new canonical question, are really the best options here, assuming that you actually want to take the time to craft an answer. You'd have to be careful when writing that canonical, though, because it would be easy for it to be "too broad" and subject to closure itself. Some users will grant you more leeway because it is meant to be a canonical, but others apply rules in very rote ways, so your mileage will vary. All in all, I don't think this little nugget of advice is worth going through too much effort to preserve/enshrine.

Comment: @CodyGray: The thinking was: "ok, this feedback from the OP clarifies the question some by helping us understand what kind of ideas they hadn't thought of yet".  Thus making me consider revising my initial judgement that the question should be closed.  But not for very long.  What made me bother asking on meta was to also ask whether caching is considered common knowledge, not really to just discuss not answering bad questions in general.